Handing in my Formal Notice
I plan to step down as Moderator around August 8, 2024.
Thank you all for the support during 2018 - 2024.
It was interesting to learn a bit about how the StackExchange system works, but now I am "ready for new challenges" as they say.
In particular I want to mention a new project, Marginis.
Its goal is to formalize small parts of research papers as well as StackExchange answers.
It includes one CSTheory post and a couple of MathOverflow posts at the moment.
If you formalize something on CSTheory, maybe together we can build a library, with unified notation, proving the correctness (or incorrectness) of parts of CSTheory.
(It would be nice to add support for live proof assistant links to the site
but I'm not sure if SE would implement that.)
